# bash: bc command's evaluation of *

Tags: bash, unix, bc

I am using the bc command in UNIX to parse some math expressions. I have two small functions:

```
function bashcalc {
      echo $@ | bc -l
}

function2 {
      ...
      catMinusMouse=$(bashcalc "$cat_angle - $mouse_angle")
      cos=$(cosine $catMinusMouse)
      val=$(bashcalc "$cat_radius * $cos")   ##PARSE ERROR
      ...
}
```

When I tried to run the expression following val, I got quite a few "(standard_in) 1: parse error"s.

My first thought was that the asterisk was the issue so I tried escaping it. That however gave me an illegal character error.

The solution ended up being removing all of the whitespace

```
   val=$(bashcalc "$cat_radius*$cos")
```

QUESTION: Why did calculating catMinusMouse (with spaces around the subtraction operator) work while the same format with multiplication did not work?

Comment: Try running `echo 2 * 3` in a non-empty directory and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: That's interesting. However, could I make this work with the use of escaping? If I do `$(bashcalc $cat_radius \* $cos)`, wouldn't I be effectively calling `echo 2 \* 2`, which properly escapes the * and doesn't list the directory?

Comment: Problem isn't at the call site, it's in the expansion of  `$@` in the function. jm666's answer covers it.

Answer (score 3):

you need escape the `*` or enclose it into "quotes"

3 variants:

```
#!/bin/bash

function bashcalc {
    echo "$@" | bc -l
}

function2() {
    cat_radius=0.9
    catMinusMouse=0.4

    val=$(bashcalc "$cat_radius" "*" "c($catMinusMouse)")
    echo $val

    #or
    val=$(bashcalc "$cat_radius * c($catMinusMouse)")
    echo $val

    #or
    val=$(bc -l <<EOF
$cat_radius * c($catMinusMouse)
EOF
)
    echo $val
}

function2
```

Comment: You should properly double-quote all variable expansions here, but the beef is the use of `"$@"` pro bare `$@`.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem here is that you have not quoted `$@` in your `bashcalc` function.

Change it to:

```
function bashcalc {
      echo "$@" | bc -l
}
```

Even better, [don't use `echo`](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/useless-use-of-echo.html). Change it to:

```
bashcalc() {
    bc -l <<< "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following:

```
val=$(echo "$cat_radius * $cos"| bc)
```

that is, pipe to `bc` (bashcalc) and it will make the calculation.

Comment: That's new. The program `bc` predates Bash by a large margin, so whatever the name stands for, it's certainly not "Bash Calculator". [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language) says it's "basic calculator".